# How to collect NUnit reports with MSBuild?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nunit

I've recently introduced NUnit to a Visual Studio C# project. The project folder structure looks like

```
- project root
-- applications (rich client interface, web interface, small tools)
-- components   (business logic)
-- vendor       (3rd party components)
-- tests        (Nunit tests)
```

For each Visual Studio project "MyProject" under applications or components there is a corresponding project under tests named "MyProject.Test". When I introduced the NUnit test, I put the following in each .Test.csproj file:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <CreateItem Include="$(TargetPath)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="MyProjectTests" />
  </CreateItem>
  <!-- Create folder for test results -->
  <MakeDir Directories="$(OutDir)\TestResults" />
  <!-- Run tests-->
  <NUnit Assemblies="@(MyProjectTests)" ToolPath="..\vendor\NUnit\bin" OutputXmlFile=".\TestResults\MyProject.Test.Results.xml" WorkingDirectory="$(OutDir)" />
  <!-- Create HTML report -->
  <Xslt Inputs="$(OutDir)\TestResults\MyProject.Test.Results.xml" Xsl="$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)\NUnitReport.xsl" RootTag="Root" Output="$(OutDir)\TestResults\MyProject.Test.Results.html" />
</Target>
```

This works fine, both when building solutions from within Visual Studio as well as on a build server with the MSBuild CLI.

The remaining inconvenience of that approach is that it leaves me with the test reports in a TestResults folder in each test projects output folder, but with nothing in my solution's main output folder. So, my question is:

What is the preferred way of collecting the resulting NUnit html reports in the solution's/startup project's output folder? What MSBuild instructions should I place in which .csproj file? I'm just getting started with MSBuild and I can't figure out the best practice...

It has to work both in Visual Studio and with the MSBuild CLI, but that shouldn't be a problem, I guess.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have a build server, one good approach is to setup a site with a virtual path configured to your test folder. Then any person on your company can browse something like http://build.companydomain.local/yourapp/nunitreports/, hosted on the build server's IIS (in case your build server have one).

I'm doing this with my coverage reports. Any person can browse it at any moment. I hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry, I haven't noticed your answer earlier. I must admit I don't quite understand how this would help me. My Tests folder contains multiple test projects, so mapping the Tests folder to a virtual path does nothing to solve the problem of having to collect the reports manually.